# matTooltip not responding to longpress action

Tags: angular, angular-material, hammer.js

matTooltip is not loading on my iPhone in Safari. I read that it should respond to a longpress, but it does not. I read that I need hammerjs in order for it to work, and I added that, but it still does not work.

This is for an Angular 5 application. I did `npm install --save hammerjs`

In my main.ts file: `import 'hammerjs';`

In my template:
`<span matTooltip="Tooltip!">I have a tooltip</span>`

The tooltip does show up normally on desktop and android phones, just not when I attempt to longpress on iPhone. Am I missing something?

Comment: Long press doesn't work for me on Android. It shows the tip only sometimes if the element has focus.

Comment: @Reactgular Do you know of any work around to this? I just tried using (click) to manually show the tooltip, but this does not work either.

Comment: I found this project that uses HammerJS. They load hammerjs in the main.ts file. I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not. https://stackblitz.com/edit/pan-gesture

Comment: also this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0

Comment: Interesting, but the default for HammerJS is to disable DOM events. This can be reconfigured via the platform-browser module. http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#hammer.manager